# Magento 2 - Routers_Match slow?

Tags: magento2, optimization

Im attempting to speed up a magento 2 store and have noticed within Profiler the step **routers_match** which takes over a 1.3s of the total time 1.7s.

Is this supposed to take this long? When the page is cached this step no longer exists which is good however am wondering if there is some more information about this step, how long it takes normally and if there is a way to speed it up?

The store is currently only 3000 products but will go up to 10000+ so am worried this will get increasingly worse.

Comment: Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer **routers_match** should take most of time on simple pages since is started within FrontController dispatch method.

This method handles your request and response so you should look deeper into routers_match to find cause of low performance.

Comment: In my case, routers_match takes too much time on product listing page. Can you please guide me how can I reduce it?